# Build Visual Studio 2015 Project in 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I'm running a Windows dualboot with both Windows 7 and Windows 10. On the Windows 7 portion, I have always had Visual Studio 2013 installed, and on the Windows 10 portion, I decided to install 2015. I do most of my programming on Windows 10, however, it would be nice to run the Visual Studio 2015 projects when I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I tried building a 2015 project in 2013, and I got the error that the `v140 toolset` is not installed. Is there any way to get the v140 toolset for 2013? If not, is there any way to make 2015 projects backwards compatible? Thanks.

Comment: Just install VS 2015 on Windows 7. It supports Windows 7 Service Pack 1 or later.

Comment: They did not have a time machine at VS2013 to guess what the v140 toolset might look like.  So the MSBuild targets just don't know where to look for it.  Rather heavy changes in v140 btw, particularly so for managed projects.  You could try editing the ToolsVersion setting in the project file to "14.0" but how much trouble you'll run into is unpredictable.